# Full text file search in Unity

Tags: unity, files, search, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the Unity dash search for content within files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37408/can-the-unity-dash-search-for-content-within-files)

I have recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 and I cannot figure out how to achieve the full text search using the file search lens. I am aware zeitgeist indexes only files I have opened already, so I deliberately open a file (odt, odp, whatever), close it, and then go to the lens and type in some of the words from the file. Surely nothing shows up, ever. So I wonder, is there something else I have to do in order to enable full text search (fts extension is installed) or is there some timing used by zeitgeist to index files? I used tracker for this purpose (even though it searched all files, not only the opened ones) in older Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Your question is answered in the answer to this question (also it's comments) - [Can the unity dash search for content within files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37408/can-the-unity-dash-search-for-content-within-files)