# Is there a way to search document contents using a Unity Lens in 14.04 Trusty?

Tags: 14.04, unity, search, lenses, recoll

In trusty 14.04, the out-of-the-box install gives you a Unity file and folder search which provides relevance-based search for recently used files (through Zeitgeist) augmented with entire filesystem search (through mlocate).

However, as far as I can tell, there is no full-text search available for all documents on the filesystem. The existing Unity search lens does *not* do full-text search of document contents; rather, only the document names themselves. There was a lens called "recoll-lens" which leveraged Recoll to do a full text search [which was packaged up through 12.04 Precise](https://launchpad.net/~recoll-backports/+archive/ubuntu/recoll-1.15-on) (as other answers mentioned back in 2011, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/116154/464073), [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/145417/464073)), but there is no official backport of recoll-lens packaged for 14.04.

Does anyone know of a repository which contains recoll-lens for 14.04, or if there are any other full-text search Unity lenses which work for 14.04?

(While I realize that 14.04 is not the last stable point release, it *is* the last stable LTS release as of the moment that I'm asking this question (10/2015), and the Ubuntu installs that I manage are on a LTS-only policy for stability).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so after more sleuthing, I've found that the `recoll-lens` package was renamed to `unity-scope-recoll`.

So, by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:recoll-backports/recoll-1.15-on
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install recoll unity-scope-recoll
```

As an aside:
I like to have my file content search results kept up to date with changes immediately(with an SSD drive this isn't a big performance issue), so I configured recoll to index immediately and to start up the indexer when I log in:

[Recoll real time indexing screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM7yf.png)

Comment: I've been having some small problems with this scope and results haven't been showing up. The developer said he's not going to further support the unity-scope and there hasn't been any updates since last March. Do you know of any other alternatives to recoll? Specially now that Ubuntu 16.04 is comming soon

Comment: Does recoll work for you on it's own? I mean can you open the recoll program itself, run a search in its own interface and get the results you want?

Comment: Yes, recoll works without a problem. The scope/lens is what doesn't work anymore and won't have further support. With the new Unity coming on Ubuntu 16.04 the scope/lens is bound to have even more problems. Any ideas on what to replace it with?

Comment: Has this situation changed any with the arrival of 16.04? It's hard to take the Unity dash seriously without features like this.

Comment: Not sure! I'm still using 14.04. I agree that it would be unfortunate if it's not provided out of the box.