# Recoll as gnome search provider

Tags: search, activities-overview, gnome-shell, recoll

I'd like to use the [recoll](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) index as a search provider in gnome 3. That is, instead of opening recoll and entering my search terms, I'd like to hit super, get [gnome overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tphTD.png), enter my search terms and get recoll results there.

This seems to be possible [in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688945/is-there-a-way-to-search-document-contents-using-a-unity-lens-in-14-04-trusty/689071#689071) but I haven't found a way to do enable it in the vanilla gnome shell.

Any advice on how to enable that in gnome?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Recoll provides a Gnome Shell Search Provide in its official downloads:

> **Gnome Shell Search Provider**
>
> This can be used with all recent Gnome Desktop versions to include Recoll
>   search results in the Gnome Shell search, and replaces the Unity Scope for
>   recent Ubuntu versions (18.04/bionic and newer).
>
> [gssp-recoll-1.0.0.tar.gz](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/downloads/gssp-recoll-1.0.0.tar.gz)
>
> Packages exist for Ubuntu (on the Recoll PPA), and Fedora (release 28 and above).

https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/download.html

To install the PPA, follow these steps (also from Recoll's downloads page):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:recoll-backports/recoll-1.15-on
sudo apt update
sudo apt install recoll
```

Finally, install the GNOME shell search provider:

```
sudo apt install gssp-recoll
```